# Как реализовать класс?

Tags: java

У меня есть абстрактный класс родитель.
У него два класса потомка. Поля каждого из них заполняются путем считывания данных из файла по заданному пути. Считывание объявляю в конструкторе каждого потомка.

Скажите, как сделать так, чтобы в классе родителе можно было в конструкторе прописать считывание данных, а в классах потомках только определять пути к нужным файлам?

```
public abstract class DSP {

private ArrayList<Campaign> listOfCampaigns;
private ArrayList<Campaign> filteredCampaigns;

DSP(String[] campaignsPath){
    listOfCampaigns = readListOfCampaigns(campaignsPath);
}

public double findBid(Request request){

    // Первичная фильтрация
    filteredCampaigns = filterCampaigns(listOfCampaigns, request);

    return 1;
}

protected ArrayList<Campaign> filterCampaigns (ArrayList<Campaign> totalListOfCampaigns, Request request){

    // Лист кампаний, прошедших первичный отбор
    ArrayList<Campaign> listOfFilteredCampaigns = new ArrayList<Campaign>();

    // Цикл по всем рекламным кампаниям
    for ( int i = 0; i < totalListOfCampaigns.size(); i++ ){ // Вот тут то и вылезает ошибка
            ...
            ...
    }

protected static ArrayList<Campaign> readListOfCampaigns(String[] campaignsPath){

    ArrayList<Campaign> listOfCampaigns = new ArrayList<Campaign>();

    JAXBContext UnmarshallingClassJAXB = null;

    for ( int i = 0; i < campaignsPath.length; i++ ){
        try {
            UnmarshallingClassJAXB = JAXBContext.newInstance(Campaign.class);
        } catch (JAXBException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Campaign campaign = (Campaign) UnmarshallingClassJAXB.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new FileInputStream(campaignsPath[i]));

            listOfCampaigns.add(campaign);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return listOfCampaigns;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вынести чтение в метод родительского класса и передавать ему `File`, `String` или `InputStream`, смотря что вам удобнее, из конструктора.

Если операция чтения - неотъемлимая часть инициализации, можно вынести ее в конструктор абстрактного родительского класса (опять-таки с параметром типа `File`, `String` или `InputStream`).

---

Примерно так:

```
public  abstract class Parent {

    protected Parent(String filename) {
        System.out.println("reading file: " + filename);
    }

}

public  class Child1 extends Parent {

    public Child1() {
        super("/some/file/path");
    }
}

public  class Child2 extends Parent {

    public Child2() {
        super("/another/file/path");
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new Child1();
        new Child2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, операция считывания неотъемлимая часть инициализации классов. 

Т.е. я могу просто реализовать конструктор абстрактного класса, и передавать к вачестве параметра путь?

Comment: @Stas0n, добавил пример. `System.out.println("reading file: " + filename);` заменяете чтением файла.

Comment: Считанные данные в абстрактном классе хранятся в ArrayList<Campaign> listOfCampaigns

Там же есть еще один метод findBid, который работает с listOfCampaigns. В нем вызывается метод filterCampaigns , которому передается в качестве параметров listOfCampaigns
Вылезает ошибка - NullPointerException

Comment: Не видя ваш код, сложно сказать, где у вас возникает NPE и из-за чего.

Comment: Добавил код в топик

Comment: Ок, но вы не показали метод `readListOfCampaigns`. Вероятно инициализация и заполнение списка проходит некорректно?

Comment: Нет, заполнение списка происходит нормально.

Answer (score 2):

В предке определяете конструктор, который имеет один параметр - имя файла. В наследниках с их конструктора вызываете этот конструктор с нужным путем.

Можно в предке объявить отдельный protected метод для загрузки, а вызывать с наследников.

Вариант три. Делается отдельный класс, который умеет правильно создавать нужный класс.

Comment: Первый вариант разве чем-то отличается от того, если бы просто в наследниках реализовывался свой конструктор?

Comment: Отличается тем, что код не дублируется в каждом наследнике.

Comment: т.е. что-то похожее на то, что написал Nofate в своем посте ниже?

Comment: да. у @Nofate хороший пример.